If $a+b+c=4, abc=-1, \frac{a}{a^2-3a-1}+ \frac{b}{b^2-3b-1}+ \frac{c}{c^2-3c-1}=\frac{4}{9}$, find $a^2+b^2+c^2$

Given that $a, b, c$ are real numbers, and
$a+b+c=4~~~(1)$
$abc=-1 ~~~(2)$
$\displaystyle \frac{a}{a^2-3a-1}+ \frac{b}{b^2-3b-1}+ \frac{c}{c^2-3c-1}=\frac{4}{9} ~~~(3)$



Find the value of $a^2+b^2+c^2.$

Why do I share this question?
When I first saw this question, I had no idea what to do for the equation $(3)$. So, I want to start with equation $(1)$ and $(2)$, I use the formula
$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc= (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac) ~~~~~(4)$
Why I use the formula? I can substitute equation $(1)$ and $(2)$ to equation $(4)$, and I get
$a^3+b^3+c^3+3=4\times(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac)~~~~~(5)$
But I don’t know how to find the value of $ab+bc+ac$ and $a^3+b^3+c^3$.

After I found the hints provided in my competition book, I know how to do this question.
I share the solution in the “Answer” section. But any other solutions for this question are welcomed.

 Hint :Substitute equation $(2)$ to equation $(3)$. Then simplify the equation $(3)$. After that, substitute equation $(1)$ to equation $(3)$. Then add all the fractions in the left hand side of that equation. Substitute the equation $(1)$ and $(2)$ again to the equation $(3)$.


$a,b,c$ are the three roots of the cubic polynomial
$$ \begin{align*} P(x) &= (x-a)(x-b)(x-c) \\
P(x) &= x^3 - (a+b+c)x^2 + (ab+bc+ca)x - abc \\
P(x) & = x^3 - 4x^2 + Kx + 1 
\end{align*}$$
where $K = ab + bc + ca$.
Let's try relating the equation $P(a)=0$ and the $a^2-3a-1$ term, by polynomial division:
$$ 0 = P(a) = a^3 - 4a^2 + Ka + 1 = (a^2-3a-1)(a-1) + (K-2)a $$
$$ \frac{a}{a^2-3a-1} = \frac{1-a}{K-2} $$
In the same way,
$$ \frac{b}{b^2-3b-1} = \frac{1-b}{K-2}, \qquad \frac{c}{c^2-3c-1} = \frac{1-c}{K-2}$$
So equation (3) gives
$$ \frac 49 = \frac{1-a}{K-2} + \frac{1-b}{K-2} + \frac{1-c}{K-2} = \frac{3-a-b-c}{K-2} = \frac{-1}{K-2} $$
Therefore $K= 2 - \frac 94 = -\frac 14$.
Finally,
$$ (a+b+c)^2 = a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca $$
$$ 4^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 2K $$
$$ a^2+b^2+c^2 = \frac{33}{2} $$

My solution:
Substitute equation $(1)$ and equation $(2)$ to equation $(3)$.
$\frac{a}{a^2-3a-1}+ \frac{b}{b^2-3b-1}+ \frac{c}{c^2-3c-1}=\frac{4}{9}$
$\frac{a}{a^2-3a+abc}+\frac{b}{b^2-3b+abc}+\frac{c}{c^2-3c+abc}=\frac{4}{9}$
The value of $a, b, c$ can't be $0$, as $abc=-1$.
Simplifying all the fractions in the left-hand side by dividing $a$ for each numerator and denominator.
$\frac{1}{a-3+bc}+\frac{1}{b-3+ac}+\frac{1}{c-3+ab}=\frac{4}{9}$
$\frac{1}{4-b-c-3+bc}+\frac{1}{4-a-c-3+ac}+\frac{1}{4-a-b-3+ab}=\frac{4}{9}$
$\frac{1}{1-b-c+bc}+\frac{1}{1-a-c+ac}+\frac{1}{1-a-b+ab}=\frac{4}{9}$
$\frac{1}{(b-1)(c-1)}+\frac{1}{(a-1)(c-1)}+\frac{1}{(a-1)(b-1)}=\frac{4}{9}$
$\frac{a+b+c-3}{(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)}=\frac{4}{9}$
$\frac{4-3}{abc-(ab+ac+bc)+a+b+c-1}=\frac{4}{9}$
$\frac{1}{-1-(ab+ac+bc)+4-1}=\frac{4}{9}$
$\frac{1}{2-(ab+bc+ac)}=\frac{4}{9}$
$9=4 [2-(ab+bc+ac)]$
$2-\frac{9}{4}=ab+bc+ac$
$ab+bc+ac=-\frac{1}{4}$
$a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ac)=4^2$
$a^2+b^2+c^2-\frac{1}{2}=16$
$a^2+b^2+c^2=\boxed{\frac{33}{2}}$
